# how to change decimal to % using .net

Tags: asp.net

I have a variable Amount in my class.

This Amount value is coming from database as decimal something .0.000654345

While displaying in grid I need to show this as % value.

Comment: Um, multiply by 100, and put a percent sign after the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by 100 and parse the result as a string and format it appropriately...

```
String parsedNum = String.Format("{0}%", num * 100);
```

Comment: +1 for using String.format and not converting the number to a string.  Note that `"{0}%"` can be changed to, for example, `"{0.00}%"` or similar to control how many digits to display after the decimal.  If you do this, the number is rounded.

Comment: Removed +1.  Michael Haren's answer is better.

Answer (score 10):

Use the ["P" format](http://blogs.msdn.com/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx), which is hopefully more aware of globalization:

```
String.Format("{0:P4}", pos); // e.g. 1,000.0000%
```

You ought to be able to use this format string directly in your Gridview, too, as others have suggested. Since it does the 100x calc for you, though, it should actually work :). Perhaps [like this](http://www.netomatix.com/development/gridviewcustomdataformatting.aspx):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Db" DataFormatString="{0:P4}" />
```

Comment: +1 For `P` format, which is something I can use to clean my own code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that really depends on what it's meant to represent in its current form.

It *may* be as simple as multiplying by 100... but it could also be 10,000 depending on the exact meaning of "Amount".

What would you want displayed for 0.000654345?

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It is a nice point (should really be a comment IMO, though), but it's not really an answer.  Or is Jon Skeet using black magic to get more reputation?

Comment: @Brian: What do you mean by "accepted"? At least it's not the accepted answer. Also, I think it's OK to answer with a question if you plan on editing your answer after getting more information.

Comment: @Matti: Jon skeet's answer was accepted, but the OP removed his acceptance later.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Double yourValue = 0.00065;
 String percentage = (yourValue*100).ToString() + "%";
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're implicitly asking a Gridview question as well, try:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"
         Text='<%# Eval("Amount", "{0:0%}") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to multiply by 100. Use this

```
Console.WriteLine("Display percentage: {0:#.##%}", num);
```

Use # depending upon the precision.